# python: How to compare values in a list by row?

Tags: python, list

i need to convert a csv into a list  and count the amount of 'z's in a row and print out the row headers of 5 rows with the top amount of Z's. Also links to more help would be great! thank you

Here is my current code

```
economistData = open('C:/foo.csv','r')
economistDataList = []s
for line in economistData:
    economistDataList.append(line.split(','))


for row in economistDataList:
    rowcnt = row.count('z')
```

Comment: it must be done in a list, i'm helping someone with school work. no csv module

Comment: Or more politely, Python's standard lib has a module for CSV files. Is there any reason not to use it? (docs: http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It can parse stuff into a 2d list but will escape stuff properly.

Comment: Although overkill, go look at pandas. You get get counts from a csv file in many different, much easier ways. Spend some time on it, enlighten yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you had to do this **without using the csv module**:

```
z_counts = []
lines = []

with open('C://foo.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() #This is your list of all the rows/lines (now populated with data)
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        #store the z counts and the index of the line as pairs using a tuple: `( ... )`
        z_counts.append((line.strip().split('z').count('z'), index))

    #Since you want the top 5 matches
    #Reverse is necessary since Python automatically sorts in ascending order
    print sorted(z_counts, reverse=True)[:5]
```

Using the following sample data:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,i,p
a,e,f,g,h,d,e,g,z,g,z
z,z,z,c,x,s,e,f,d,s,f
q,e,r,s,f,t,y,y,u,i,f
e,p,l,l,k,k,z,z,q,e,r
o,i,i,j,l,s,w,e,r,q,g
w,e,r,f,g,s,v,h,d,b,z
t,r,y,e,u,i,o,p,d,f,j
```

Which, if you observe, has the following z counts:

```
0
2
3
0
2
0
1
0
```

We obtain the following output (a list of tuples with the sorted corresponding z counts, and the index of that z count):

```
[(3, 2), (2, 4), (2, 1), (1, 6), (0, 7)]
```

OUTPUT:

Let's print it out to see what it looks like:

```
for tpl in sorted(z_counts, reverse=True)[:5]:
    print lines[tpl[1]]
```

Which outputs:

```
z,z,z,c,x,s,e,f,d,s,f     #3 z's, line index 2 (3rd line)
e,p,l,l,k,k,z,z,q,e,r     #2 z's, line index 4 (5th line)
a,e,f,g,h,d,e,g,z,g,z     #2 z's, line index 1 (2nd line)
w,e,r,f,g,s,v,h,d,b,z     #1 z, line index 6 (7th line)
t,r,y,e,u,i,o,p,d,f,j     #0 z's, line index 7 (8th line)
```

As expected.